# Dynamic SQL Query to Drop table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

Looking for way to create some dynamic SQL to drop a table if it exists. However I can not seem to get the syntax correct. Here is the query so far (renamed fields for security)

```
DECLARE @TableNameNew NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DynamicSQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TableNameNew = (SELECT  'tbl1_' + REPLACE(StaffCode,'.','') AS TableName
         FROM tblEmployee WHERE (PCLogin = REPLACE(SYSTEM_USER, 'DOMAIN\', '')))
SET @DynamicSQL2 = 'IF OBJECT_ID(' + '''' + @TableNameNew + '''' + +','+'''U''' + ') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + @TableNameNew

EXEC @DynamicSQL2
```

This returns an error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'IF OBJECT_ID('tbl1_ghewitt','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tbl1_ghewitt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL2
```

instead of

```
EXEC @DynamicSQL2
```

Comment: Perfect. Appreciated!